# Recursion doesn't do what its supposed to be doing

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a function that takes an integer value and returns a list of [i/2, i/3, i/4] wher i != 0. I also have a recursion that's supposed to calculate the function(i) to the point where it can't due to reaching 0. Then, I calculate how many zeroes are there in the list and output it.

C#:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int zeroes = 0;

        List<int> myList = ATM(input);

        foreach(var number in myList.ToArray())
        {
            if (number != 0)
            {
                myList.AddRange(ATM(number));
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        foreach (var zero in myList)
        {
            if (zero == 0)
            {
                zeroes += 1;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(zeroes);
        Console.ReadKey();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static List<int> ATM(int value)
    {
        List<int> exchangeCoins = new List<int>();

        if (value != 0)
        {
            exchangeCoins.Add(value / 2);
            exchangeCoins.Add(value / 3);
            exchangeCoins.Add(value / 4);
        }
       else
        {
            throw new Exception("Value can't be zero!");
        }

        return exchangeCoins;

    }
}
```

7 is supposed to return 15 0s but it returns 6 zeroes. Why?

Comment: *7 is supposed to return 15 0s but it returns 6 zeroes. Why?* - Debug

Comment: I'm maybe blind but I don't see the recursion?

Comment: I see `ATM` before the `foreach` and inside the `foreach` call but I don't see `ATM` calling itself again (and I do suppose that `main` shouldn't be calling itself again), so I also don't see `recursion`.
Also what is `function(i)` ? Would that allude to `ATM` as that is the only method with an integer argument, asssuming `i` is `integer`.
Could you please rephrase your question to explain exactly what it is that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's step through your code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int input = 7;
        int zeroes = 0;

        List<int> myList = ATM(input);
```

> mylist => `[3,2,1]`

```
        foreach(var number in myList.ToArray())
        {
            if (number != 0)
            {
                myList.AddRange(ATM(number));
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
```

> - after 3 mylist => `[3,2,1,1,1,0]`
> - after 2 mylist => `[3,2,1,1,1,0,1,0,0]`
> - after 1 mylist => `[3,2,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]`

```
        }
```

> count the zeros by hand ... and you see 6 zeros

```
        foreach (var zero in myList)
        {
            if (zero == 0)
            {
                zeroes += 1;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(zeroes);
        Console.ReadKey();


        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static List<int> ATM(int value)
    {
        List<int> exchangeCoins = new List<int>();

        if (value != 0)
        {                                 // 7 3 2 1
            exchangeCoins.Add(value / 2); // 3 1 1 0
            exchangeCoins.Add(value / 3); // 2 1 0 0
            exchangeCoins.Add(value / 4); // 1 0 0 0
        }
       else
        {
            throw new Exception("Value can't be zero!");
        }

        return exchangeCoins;

    }
}
```

Thats why your code returns 6

---

If your goal is to get 15 zeros then you have to design ATM being recursive:

```
static void Main( string[ ] args )
{
    int input = int.Parse( Console.ReadLine() );
    int zeroes = 0;

    List<int> myList = ATM( input );

    foreach ( var zero in myList )
    {
        if ( zero == 0 )
        {
            zeroes += 1;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine( zeroes );
    Console.ReadKey();


    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Recursive call in ATM

```
static List<int> ATM( int value )
{
    List<int> exchangeCoins = new List<int>();

    if ( value != 0 )
    {
        exchangeCoins.Add( value / 2 );
        exchangeCoins.Add( value / 3 );
        exchangeCoins.Add( value / 4 );

        // recursive call on the three items
        foreach ( var item in exchangeCoins.ToArray() )
        {
            exchangeCoins.AddRange( ATM( item ) );
        }
    }

    return exchangeCoins;

}
```

Comment: I was completely lost on recursion. It's fixed now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know that 7 is supposed to return 15 0s ?

The first iteration, you will have 3 entries

*x1*, *x2* and *x3*

After that, for each entry (3 entries) you will have at best 3 entries more

*x1* generates *x11*, *x12* and *x13*
*x2* generates *x21*, *x22* and *x23*
*x3* generates *x31*, *x32* and *x33*

So 9 entries more. In total: 9 + 3 = 12

How can you then have 15 0s if you will have at best 12 numbers??